# Конфликт версий при импорте SBT проекта (Play Framework) в IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2

Tags: intellij-idea, импорт, playframework, проект, sbt

Что изменить в проекте или настройках IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2, чтобы не появлялось сообщение при открытии проекта:

[image: SBT project import]

[image: sbt.version]

Создавал приложение с помощью Typesafe Activator, Play 2.5.0-M1 (activator)

```
SBT project import
[warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version: [warn] * org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:(4.0.1, 4.3.4) [warn] * com.google.guava:guava:(18.0, 16.0.1) [warn] * org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:(4.0.1, 4.3.2) [warn] * commons-logging:commons-logging:(1.1.1, 1.1.3) [warn] * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:(1.0.1, 1.0.3) [warn] * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:(1.0.1, 1.0.3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Редактировать файл **build.sbt**, добавив в него следующие строки:

dependencyOverrides += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.3.4"

dependencyOverrides += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "18.0"

dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-parser-combinators_2.11" % "1.0.3"

dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.3"

[Документация](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version)